# How to add a favicon to a xhtml document

Tags: xhtml, favicon

I made a windows icon (*.ico) and named it favicon, it is 16 by 16 and with 16 colors... I have included it with the link tag

but it does not load right

> how do I add a favicon to a website in xhtml

I tried everything on the web but it still does not work

> how do I do it

Comment: How did you make the icon? Are you sure it's *really* a Windows icon and not some other type renamed? A file called `favicon.ico` in the web root should normally be used even without a `<link/>` pointing to it. The link itself is not really any different in XHTML compared to plain old HTML, you just need the self-closing syntax as in Robert's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://yourdomain.com/youricon.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Upload the .ico to your root directory and add this in your XHTML header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

The favicon may not appear right away. Depending on what browser you're using, you may need to clear your cache or even bookmark the website.

Comment: Just want to confirm that if browsers has detected that there aren't a favicon, they make an effort to not ask for it again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following markup to your html's head:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico">
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 0):

you may place the ico in your root directory and add code like this line

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```